# Hiding and unhiding columns - Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Very much an amateur here so please do bear with me.

I am creating a workbook that contains 4 sheets. The sheet is populated with data from another sheet and contains names.

Some values will be empty when it first loads and so I want the rows with empty values not to show.

My plan was to code it so that when it opens, the column unhides all the data, then code it to spot where there are blanks and hide that row.

I have used the following code:

```
    function unHideColumn(y7)
    { 
      var s = ss.getSheetByName("Year 7");
      var columnRange = s.getRange("A:A");
      var datarange = s.unhideColumn(columnRange);
    }

    function onOpen(y7) {
      var a = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('YEAR 7');
      a.showRows(1, a.getMaxRows());

      a.getRange('A:A')
        .getValues()
        .forEach( function (r, i) {
        if (r[0] == '') 
          a.hideRows(i + 1);
        });
    }
```

This gets the desired outcome on the first sheet but there are 3 other sheets. If I use the same code again with a different sheet name it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute the code for **every sheet** in your spreadsheet file by iterating the `ss.getSheets()` array with a `forEach()` loop:

```
function unHideColumn(y7)
{ 
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Year 7");
  var columnRange = s.getRange("A:A");
  var datarange = s.unhideColumn(columnRange);
}

function onOpen(y7) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
     
  sheets.forEach(a=>{  
  a.showRows(1, a.getMaxRows());
  a.getRange('A:A')
    .getValues()
    .forEach( function (r, i) {
    if (r[0] == '') 
      a.hideRows(i + 1);
    })});
   
}
```

If you want to execute the code for **specific sheets** based on their name then try this instead:

```
function unHideColumn(y7)
{ 
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Year 7");
  var columnRange = s.getRange("A:A");
  var datarange = s.unhideColumn(columnRange);
}

    function onOpen(y7) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheets = ['Sheet1','Sheet4']; // choose specific sheets
     
  sheets.forEach(sh=>{  
  var a = ss.getSheetByName(sh);
  a.showRows(1, a.getMaxRows());
  a.getRange('A:A')
    .getValues()
    .forEach( function (r, i) {
    if (r[0] == '') 
      a.hideRows(i + 1);
    })});
   
}
```

for example, this will be executed only for `'Sheet1'` and `'Sheet4'`.